# To retrieve Event Description, do I need an access token?

Tags: events, facebook-login

I created an app, so I'm using my appId and secret. I can retrieve an event array for any page that has public events using:

```
// Lady Gaga example (not a fan!)
$event_array = $facebook->api('/ladygaga/events');
```

The returned array gives me:

```
[name]
[start_time]
[end_time]
[timezone]
[location]
[id]
```

I wish [description] was in there, I'd be done! This is for a community event calendar and I'd like my members to be able to add their facebook events if they choose to. I was hoping they could tell me their facebook username and I could print their events out (easy!).

**Here's the question:** Do I need to Facebook Login to show descriptions for their events? If so, how would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two different questions here.

**Page Events**: if you're just querying a page's events like `ladygaga`, you can get the description by requesting `fields` in your API call.

```
'/ladygaga/events?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,description,id'
```

(Once you specify a `fields` parameter, you need to manually request all the fields you need.)

As long as the page owner has not set any access restrictions, you can get these details by authenticating with just your `appid` and `secret`.

**User Events**: If you want to show the events that belong to a `user`, or if you are querying a page with restrictions, then a user needs to login to your app with the `user_events` permission. You need to also request `friend_events` if you want to see their friend's events too.

You violate Facebook's TOS if you store the results from one user and show them to other users.